# Pass HTML File from Django View To Django Template

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to pass through an html file from my Django view via a django template. This is my view:

```
def sample_function(request, product_id, slug=None):
  from django.template import loader
  product_data = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
  country_code = request.session.get('country_code')
  form = CountryForm(initial={'country': country_code})
  form_estimate = CountryEstimateForm(initial={'country_estimate': country_code})


  test = loader.get_template('home/custom_options.html')


  return render(request, 'request_custom_order.html', {'product':product_data,'country': form, 'country_estimate': form_estimate,'test':test})
```

This is my html:

```
<div>


{{ test }}

</div>
```

However, if I just do {{ test }} I get:

<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x7fcd03203080>

If I do {{ test|safe }} I just get blank.

Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the file? Just type the contents of the template you want to pass into the other one.

Comment: Hey there! Because I want to dynamically pass through fairly large html forms based on various criteria. I thought it would be easier to manage by keeping each form in its own file. Otherwise I think the view file would get out of control really quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is a `Template` object. You need the get its content as a string

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
...
test = render_to_string('home/custom_options.html')
```